# How to update laravel/homestead?

Tags: laravel, homestead

I need to update laravel/homestead? It is a Vagrant box. I'm using it for my dev environment.

I remember it was a shell command but I don't remember the command and I cannot find it. Please help

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#updating-homestead

Answer (score 15):

This is the sequence I came up with recently (Apr 2020) to upgrade my vagrant box from 9.2.x to 9.5.x

If the VM is not running first do:

```
vagrant up
```

Then go into the VM:

```
vagrant ssh
```

and back up the databases:

```
mysqldump -u homestead --all-databases -p > homestead-backup.sql
```

copy the resulting file to the host machine (only if the above command was *not* run in a mapped folder)

Close the ssh connection:

```
exit
```

then run:

```
vagrant box update
vagrant destroy
vagrant box prune
```

Answer yes to all questions. Then

```
git fetch
git pull origin release
```

Start the VM again:

```
vagrant up
```

once it's started (it will take longer this time) go into the VM:

```
vagrant ssh
```

and restore the databases (copy the backup file over from the host if it was not in the mapped folder)

```
mysql -u homestead -p < homestead-backup.sql
```

Note: add **-p** if needed to mysql import and export, it will prompt for password (default: "secret")

Comment: Yikes! Is there no way to update homestead without destroying and recreating your entire VM project?

Comment: Agree. But here's what Laravel official docs say: 
"Vagrant boxes are completely disposable. If something goes wrong, you can destroy and re-create the box in minutes!"

Comment: ```mysql -u -p homestead < homestead-backup.sql```  password: secret

Answer (score 6):

Use below command

```
homestead update
```

If this doesn't work

```
homestead box update
```

If this also doesn't work at all

This command will tell you the state of all active Vagrant environments on the system for the currently logged in user.

```
vagrant global-status

vagrant box update "laravel/homestead"
```

I hope i am clear now!

Comment: my box id is laravel/homestead - should I take it in quotes?

Comment: vagrant global-status - why do I need it? Sorry, your answer is not clear.

Comment: Have you tried above 2? if they fail   check status of your vagrant

Comment: i added explanation for `vagrant global-status` see my edited answer

Answer (score 3):

First update your box:

```
vagrant box update
```

And, as it is documented here:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead#updating-homestead

You should first destroy the machine and recreate it:

```
vagrant destroy
vagrant up
```

Just tested and it worked for me. (updated from homestead: '8.2.0' to '9.0.0')

Do not forget to backup your existing database datas before destroying the machine.

Comment: But how do you update homestead without destroying the whole box?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this url which will guide you to update the laravel/homestead

[Update laravel homestead](https://w3guy.com/update-laravel-homestead-vagrant-box/)

also the basic steps is `cd` into your homestead directory and run `vagrant box update` it will download the latest version

Comment: Thanks. `$ vagrant box update` worked for me. The link is unpleasant though. It suggests to backup database, when it is not needed. My database was intact after update, I don't even want to finish reading it.

Comment: I agree with @YevgeniyAfanasyev. That article does not work. I ended up a mess.

Answer (score 2):

First, check the available homestead releases:
https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases

To check your homestead and vagrant versions use these commands:

- for the Vagrant version:

`vagrant version`

I had Installed Version: 2.2.10, the last version for mac was 2.2.14

- for the Homestead version, go to the folder **~\Homestead** and:

`git branch -v`

In my case, I had this output: HEAD detached at v11.4.0

**Then, how to update Vagrant and Homestead?**
First, make sure you backup the DB!
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#database-backups

In my case, the automatic backup didn't work, and the first time I did the **vagrant destroy** I lost the DBs, so I suggest to backup manually like this:

```
vagrant ssh
mysqldump -u homestead -p --all-databases > homestead-20210214.sql
```

Then copy file out from the Vagrant machine before destroying:
from ~/Homestead

```
scp -P 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/homestead-20210214.sql .
```

Then from the Homestead directory:

```
vagrant destroy
git fetch
```

To check the version of your homestead:

```
vagrant box list
```

In my case, I had:
`laravel/homestead     (virtualbox, 10.1.1)`

Here you can check the latest stable release of Homestead:
https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases.
In my case was Homestead 12.

But actually what you are going to install is the latest stable release of the **laravel/homestead Vagrant box**.
You can see the latest release here.
https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead.
In my case was v11.0.0

Then since in my case, the latest Homestead was v12.0.0 I did:

```
git checkout v12.0.0
vagrant box update
bash init.sh
vagrant up
```

And you are done.
Then you can restore the DBs.

How if I run

```
vagrant box list
```

I see:
`laravel/homestead     (virtualbox, 11.0.0)`

Have a look also at the official documentation here.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#updating-homestead

Answer (score 1):

If you used a default settings on installation, you need

1) go to your vagrant folder

```
$ cd ~/Homestead/
```

2) run `vagrant box update` command

```
$ vagrant box update "homestead-7"
```

Tested on Laravel 5.6/5.7

Comment: You should accept your answer if you found solution by yourself